# How to fix 'Fatal Signal 11' when re-drawing onto SKCanvas

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, skiasharp

I'm trying to redraw a shape displayed on a SKCanvas the method (ChangeShape) works fine the 1st time it's called from the PaintSurface handler but when I attempt to call it again the app crashes and I receive the error "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)".

I have tried to call the handler directly and Initialise a completely new SKSurface, but it still results in the same error.

```
public LinearLayout ImageDivisionLayout_Obj;
public SKCanvasView ImageViewActivity_Obj;
public SKSurface ImageCanvas;
public SKCanvas canvasSK;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_image);

    ImageViewActivity_Obj = new SKCanvasView(this);
    ImageViewActivity_Obj.PaintSurface += ImageViewActivity_Obj_PaintSurface;
    ImageDivisionLayout_Obj = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.ImageLayoutDivision);
    ImageDivisionLayout_Obj.AddView(ImageViewActivity_Obj);
```

```
private void ImageViewActivity_Obj_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
    SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
    ImageCanvas = surface;
    SetupCanvas();
}

public void SetupCanvas()
{
    ShapePaint = new SKPaint();
    ShapePaint.Color = SKColor.Parse("#F00000");
    ShapePaint.StrokeWidth = 25;
    ShapePaint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;

    ImageCanvas.Canvas.DrawBitmap(
        AndroidExtensions.ToSKBitmap(ImageTaken),
        new SKRect(0, 0, ImageViewActivity_Obj.Width, 
        ImageViewActivity_Obj.Height));

    ChangeShape();

    ImageCanvas.Canvas.Save();
}

public void ChangeShape()
{
    float X1 = CurrentShape.X;
    float Y1 = CurrentShape.Y;
    float X2 = CurrentShape.X + CurrentShape.width;
    float Y2 = CurrentShape.Y + CurrentShape.height;

    if (CurrentShape.name == "Rectangle")
    {
        ImageCanvas.Canvas.DrawRect(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, ShapePaint);
    }
    else if (CurrentShape.name == "Circle")
    {
        ImageCanvas.Canvas.DrawCircle(new SKPoint(X2 - X1, Y2 - Y1), CurrentShape.width / 2, ShapePaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide one sample at github, because your code is not incomplete, I will download your sample to try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT https://github.com/atzin-em/ChromaticArrangerAndroid

Comment: ,I download your sample, but I can find .sln file, so  can not run your sample at my side.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT https://github.com/atzin-em/ChromaticArranger Sorry I Reuploaded let me know if that works

Comment: I try your code and app crash when call ChangeShape method twice, so I want to know why you call this method twice?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT It gets called 1st to setup the canvas and incidentally gets called an addtional time from the setting up of the spinner box to draw the shape that is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at what you are doing, I can see that this probably will not work on most platforms. The `SKSurface` that you are storing in the `ImageCanvas` field will be destroyed as soon as you leave the `ImageViewActivity_Obj_PaintSurface` method. The surface and canvas objects are transient and only live as long as the method is running.

I am assuming you are trying to create some sort of drawing app? If so, there are two approaches to this (although the smarter people may suggest more). You can either store all the operations in a list of some sort. Basically, if I draw a rectangle, store the operation and the bounds.

Or, you can create a background surface with `SKSurface.Create(...)` and then draw on that. When drawing to the screen, just copy the image from the background canvas to the screen canvas. Then, you can also just save the background canvas without trying to capture the screen canvas to save to disk.

I did a simple finger paint app here that you can check out for ideas: https://github.com/mattleibow/SkiaSharpDemo/blob/master/SkiaSharpDemo/SkiaSharpDemo/MainPage.xaml.cs